# How am I supposed to efficiently communicate between all running PHP scripts?

Tags: php, command-line-interface, share, shared-memory

I always have many PHP CLI scripts running, doing all kinds of things.

A recurring problem for all these years, which nobody has ever answered me when I've asked (and I've asked *many* times...) has been that of trying to share data between these separate processes. For example:

> Hey, other PHP scripts! I'm going to do a truncate of these database log tables now, so kindly don't try to write to them until I'm done, okay?

The only way I've found to do this is to abuse the poor database by constantly looking for "messages" in a special table, which seems insanely inefficient even if we assume that PostgreSQL (which is the database I use) stores such a small table in RAM.

The only thing I've been linked to is this "shmop" thing ( https://www.php.net/Shmop ), which is so insanely cryptic and impossible to comprehend that I've given up repeatedly for all these years when trying to use it. I've plown down countless hours of my life on that alone, without ever getting anywhere. I can never figure out how to share simple variables between PHP scripts.

Why did they not simply make a simple, nice `$_SHARED` super-superglobal? Then I could do this:

```
$_SHARED['halt database logging'] = true;
```

And then simply check in the other scripts:

```
if ($_SHARED['halt database logging']) { ... }
```

Wouldn't that have been sweet and perfect? I will never understand why this was not implemented even in the early days of PHP. It sure would've saved me unspeakable amounts of grief.

Comment: Are you just mentioning database as an example? because database engines already have the concept of rows/tables/columns locking. Not sure why you want PHP to handle the this issue.

Comment: _"I will never understand why this was not implemented even in the early days of PHP."_ Why didn't Henry Ford just put wings on his cars? It's not that simple. :)

Comment: It was an example, but also related to what I'm trying to solve right now.

Comment: If you're looking to share *data* between scripts, there's (generally) nothing wrong with a database. That's precisely what they're for. What's the actual problem you're trying to solve and in what way is a database insufficient?

Comment: Have a look at  [memcached](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.memcached.php). Way easier to use compared to shmop.

Comment: I dont know what exactly your scripts do. But having a main-script which organizes them all may be useful, depending on your scripts: [async](https://github.com/spatie/async)

Comment: Here are a few questions: 
- Are all your scripts running on the same machine?
- Do they all access the database individually?
- Could you create a service for accessing the database that queues and controls requests.